# Oval/quadrupole characterization

Tags: differential-geometry, geometry

**Context:**

Points on a circle satisfy the equation: $$x^2+y^2=r^2$$

where $r$ is the radius. In a similar manner one can show for an ellipse:

$$\frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2}=1$$

is satisfied($a$ and $b$ being the short and long radii.)

---

**Questions:**

- What is the general characteristic equation of an oval, or equivalently a quadrupole? (Is the one given in the appendix already in its general form?)
- Furthermore, how does the symmetry group of an oval differ from an ellipsoid, when the latter has 2 mirror symmetries along its main two axes? It being a quadrupole gives it higher symmetries or less?

---

**Appendix:**

In this [paper](http://arxiv.org/pdf/chao-dyn/9611006v1.pdf), a short explanation on oval parametrization is given, but the written equations aren't so straightforwardly clear (unlike ellipse/circle cases), from which I quote:

> An oval-shape has a parameterization which expresses the radius of
>   curvature $R$ of the boundary as a function of the angle $\psi$
>   between the tangent vector and the $x$-direction
>   $$R(\psi)=1+\delta\cos(2\psi)$$
>
> where $\psi$ lies in the range $[0, 2\pi)$. From this definition the
>   dependence of the $x$- and $y$-coordinates on $\psi$ follows as $$
>  x(\psi)=\sin(\psi)+\frac{\delta}{2}\sin(\psi)+\frac{\delta}{6}\sin(3\psi) $$
>   $$
> y(\psi)=-\cos(\psi)+\frac{\delta}{2}\cos(\psi)-\frac{\delta}{6}\cos({3\psi})
>  $$

**Three visualisations:**

$\delta=0.1$:

[image]

$\delta=0.4$:

[image]

$\delta=0.8$:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thought I should leave an answer so that comments to me do not keep cluttering up Robert's thread. The thing more likely to be worth your time, but still easier than your original, is
$$ x^6 + y^6 + A \left( x^4 y^2 + x^2 y^4 \right) = 1.  $$
For $A=0,$ this is convex and very close to the square, but with rounded corners. For $A = -1/2,$ the curve includes $(1,0), (-1,0), (0,1), (0,-1),$ true for all $A,$ but $A = -1/2$ also includes   $(1,1), (1,-1), (-1,1), (-1,-1).$ Indeed, it is not convex for any $A < 0.$ With $A = -1$ it is not possible to have $y = \pm x,$ the curve has split into four hyperbola-like arcs; perhaps one can find out exactly what those are by factoring; yes,
$$  x^6 - x^4 y^2 - x^2 y^4 + y^6 = (x^2 + y^2) \left(x^2 - y^2 \right)^2 $$

Now, the interesting thing for you is that $A=3$ gives a circle,
$$  x^6 +3 x^4 y^2 +3 x^2 y^4 + y^6 =  \left(x^2 + y^2 \right)^3, $$ and your highest degree terms are
$$  729  \left( x^6 +3 x^4 y^2 +3 x^2 y^4 + y^6  \right) = 729 \left(x^2 + y^2 \right)^3 $$

I mentioned about $45^\circ$ rotation. If I start with the curve using constant $A,$ then rotate coordinates so 
$$  x = \frac{u-v}{\sqrt 2}, \; \; \;  x = \frac{u-v}{\sqrt 2}, $$ I got
$$ x^6 + y^6 + A \left( x^4 y^2 + x^2 y^4 \right) = C \left( u^6 + v^6 + \left( \frac{15-A}{1+A} \right) \left( u^4 v^2 + u^2 v^4 \right) \right)  $$ where the constant $C$ depends upon $A.$ So, when $A=3,$ we get the new value of $A$ as $\frac{15-3}{1+3} =\frac{12}{4} =3, $ from circle to circle. If we start with $A=0,$ the boundary value for convexity, the new $A$ value is $15.$

Comment: @Phonon, I saw the top order terms in Robert's answer, and thought you would be helped by seeing just that part...it is the lower degree terms that spoil some of the symmetries.

Answer (score 1):

Expanding out the sin and cos of $3 \psi$, writing $\sin(\psi) = s$ and $\cos(\psi) = c$, and then eliminating $s$ and $c$ using a Groebner basis, I get
the rather unpleasant equation
$$
729\,{x}^{6}+2187\,{x}^{4}{y}^{2}+ \left( 1215\,{\delta}^{2}-4374\,
\delta-729 \right) {x}^{4}+2187\,{x}^{2}{y}^{4}+ \left( -6318\,{\delta
}^{2}-1458 \right) {x}^{2}{y}^{2}+ \left( 432\,{\delta}^{4}-3888\,{
\delta}^{3}+6480\,{\delta}^{2}+3888\,\delta \right) {x}^{2}+729\,{y}^{
6}+ \left( 1215\,{\delta}^{2}+4374\,\delta-729 \right) {y}^{4}+
 \left( 432\,{\delta}^{4}+3888\,{\delta}^{3}+6480\,{\delta}^{2}-3888\,
\delta \right) {y}^{2}-64\,{\delta}^{6}+1152\,{\delta}^{4}-5184\,{
\delta}^{2} = 0$$

Comment: the degree 6 terms are symmetric in $x,y$ though, and all exponents even. Compare $x^4 + x^2 y^2 + y^4 = 1$ in the plane, or $$ x^6 + y^6 + z^6 + A (y^2 z^4 + y^4 z^2 + z^2 x^4 + z^4 x^2 + x^2 y^4 + x^4 y^2) + B x^2 y^2 z^2 = C  $$ in $\mathbb R^3$

Comment: @phonon, just an example. $A,B,C$ are real constants. Careful choices make a surface much like a cube but rounded, with 26 integer lattice points with $|x|,|y|,|z| \leq 1$ on the surface, just not $(0,0,0)$ itself. In the plane, just $$ x^4 + A x^2 y^2 + y^4 = 1,  $$ real constant $A.$

Comment: @Phonon, quite sure, but the figures are convex only for something like $0 \leq A \leq 4,$ do not actually recall the upper bound. Also, as soon as $A > 2,$ you are simply giving a $45^\circ$ rotation to another. Anyway, try $A=1;$ note that $A=2$ is a circle.

Comment: @Phonon, wrote it out, I get convex for $0 \leq A \leq 6,$ and the figure with $A=6$ should be a rotated (and scaled) version of $A=0.$ I have no idea how this relates to physics.

Comment: Since all exponents are even, the curve is invariant under the reflections $x \to -x$ and $y \to -y$. Unless $\delta = 0$, these are all the symmetries.

Comment: The ellipsoid has more (linear) symmetries.  If you write the ellipsoid as $X^T A X = 1$ where $A$ is a (symmetric) positive definite $2 \times 2$ matrix, $X \to T X$ is a symmetry of the ellipsoid if $T^T A T = I$, i.e.
$T = A^{-1/2} S$ where $S$ is an orthogonal matrix.

Comment: A circle is preserved by rotations.  Given an ellipse, first transform it to a circle, then rotate, then transform back.